# Shared code logical address in process address space

Tags: memory-management, operating-system

In "Operating Systems Concepts" book of Silberchatz , it says

"Shared code must appear in same location in the logical address space of all processes" ,

Why does it have to appear in same location ? I thought that for each process we have a separate Page table , which makes it possible to have share code address in different logical addresses !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Machine code is rarely fully position-independent. If you have some code that's been compiled to work when located at address 0x10000 (logical/virtual) and you move it to address 0x70000 (logical/virtual), it won't work at the new location.

Page tables can't help with this. What can is code/data addressing modes relative to the `instruction pointer` (AKA `program counter`). Some CPUs have it, some don't have it, yet some others have it half-baked (e.g. they can have it only for instructions that transfer control (e.g. `jump`/`call`) to other places in code, but nothing for data (e.g. `move`)).

Comment: From what i make of what you said,
When shared code has to reference itself, It needs to know the logical address space it is in. Since shared code can't change itself for each process accessing it, This means the logical address space must be constant across all shared processes.

Wouldn't this also mean you can't use 2 pieces of shared code which use the same logical address space?

Comment: @2bigpigs Shared code can work with data located at different places if it's designed and compiled in such a way that in every address space the caller supplies it with the address of the data or said address can be somehow obtained from the environment (e.g. TLS and such). Obviously, you can't have intersecting code/data within the same address space at the same time. But I think, shared code does not have to be shared perfectly. If you can't have a library at the same address in one address space as in all others, you can have another copy of the library relocated to a different location.

Answer (score 0):

every address, like jump-to addresses, used in the library (shared code) is fixed pointing to the specific logical address.
Therefore, those logical addresses shall be the same in all processes that have imported this library.
It means that you could only place this library in the exact same logical address to let the library find its own code